# Setting SOLR_JAVA_MEM for Solr 4.3

Tags: tomcat, solr4

I have a Solr cloud 4.3 cluster on AWS. The servers have each 16gb of memory but when I look in the web admin I can see that -Xmx are set to Xmx6656m.
I have search for this setting in all files but can't find it. I know I can start Solr manually and set the parameters but there must be a correct way to do it.

Goal: SOLR_JAVA_MEM="-Xms10g -Xmx10g"

[image]

Comment: That's an oddly-*specific* heap size. Are you not able to `grep` through your various launch scripts to find it? Or even just search for either `-Xm` or `SOLR_JAVA_MEM`?

Comment: I have used grep to search all my files but only got one hit, - my bash history

Answer (score 2):

First I really got to improve my grep skills (;

I found the setting in "/etc/default/tomcat7" at the line starting with "JAVA_OPTS".
I changed the parameter to -Xms10g -Xmx10g and restarted the server with "sudo service tomcat7 stop" then "sudo service tomcat7 start"

It is first at Solr version 5 that the added the bin directory where there has files for configuring memory setting.